# SEO issues of htaccess 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

A website currently has both naked and www subdomain working, but distinct. Can see www.domain.com/page and domain.com/page. I was going to redirect the naked domain to the www using htaccess and a 301 redirect. However, most of the site's top SERP results are it turns out the naked domain. Since the site depends heavily on its revenue from its top SERP listings, is there any SEO issue to be aware of in doing a 301 htaccess redirect from the www to the naked domain? I've been reading what I can find online, but thought I should check in with the wisdom of StackOverflow before making a major change. They are quite worried about doing anything, because they currently have decent rankings. I think the rankings would be much better without what must look like duplicate content to search engines and to consolidate  on a single domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set in your Google Webmaster Tools account that you prefer the version of your site with www. ? It should be enough to avoid duplicate content and have only the www. version of your site in the SERP.

Comment: Does that setting in Webmaster give all the SEO benefit of a 301?